# Is there a way to add a timer to a python programm?

Tags: python-3.x, time

Im not very good with programming but im currently doing a multiplication learning programm for my brother and was wandering if there is any way to do it, so that he has to answer after a certain ammoun of time or else he fails the question. Here is my Code:

```
import random
F = 1

while F==1:
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    y = random.randint(1,10)
    Result = y*x
    
    print(y,"*",x)
    Input = int(input())
    
    if Result == Input:
        print("correct")
        
    else:
        print("Wrong, correct result:",Result)
```

I hope this is good enough. I would appreciate any help! Thank a lot in advande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `threading` module to create a thread and assign timer to that thread, if the timer runs out that means the sub thread is dead now the program will respond you got late.
Here's the solution:

```py
import random
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def timer():
    sleep(10)                                                       # wait for 10 seconds once the question is asked
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        x = random.randint(1, 10)
        y = random.randint(1, 10)
        Result = y * x

        print(y, "*", x)
        time = Thread(target=timer)                                 # Creating sub thread for timer processing
        time.start()                                                # starting the thread
        Input = int(input())
        if not time.isAlive():                                      # checking whether the timer is alive
            print('You got late, Failed')
            break
        else:
            pass

        if Result == Input:
            print("correct")

        else:
            print("Wrong, correct result:", Result)
```

if you use `time.sleep()` method on your main thread your program will hung up and so do your system as well for the time being, so instead of doing that I created a new thread which works completely independent of your main thread and your system will not hung up.

Comment: You can increase the time limit as well by altering the value of parameter given to sleep() method

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own using the Python's time module.
For example:

```
def timer(t):#t must be the time of the timer in seconds
    while t:
        mins,sec=divmod(t,60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        t=t-1
    print("Time's Up")
```